# Getting "invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII" when I try to upload a file in Ramaze and Ruby 1.9

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9, ramaze

I guess the default encodings have changed with 1.9, but I thought Ramaze was supposed to be fully 1.9 compatible? I'm really not sure what going on here. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found this commit which was added to the tree 3 days after the 1.0 release:

http://github.com/rack/rack/commit/44ed4640f077504a49b7f1cabf8d6ad7a13f6441

Patching didn't work, but cloning HEAD and replacing my installation did. It's still pretty tough to develop a Ruby 1.9 app... but it can only get easier!